# Showing undefined variable while updating image in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am totally new in laravel and i have a small error in my code. Whenever I am updating the image it is showing the error

```
Undefined variable: company_image
```

Here is my code in Controller :

```
if(isset($request->company_image) && $request->company_image->getClientOriginalName()) {
    $ext = $request->company_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;     
    $request->company_image->storeAs('public/company-logo',$file);
}
else
{
    if(!$company_image){
        $file='';
    }
    else
    {
        $file = $company_image;
    }
}
```

Here is my code in resource :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">                           
        <div class="col-md-3">                      
            <label>Company Image</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="file" name="company_image" id="imageUpload" class="hide"> 
            <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-poster mr-5">Select file</label> Max Size 2 MB<br>
            @if($company_image)
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/company-logo/'.$company_image)}}" class="organisation-logo">
            @else
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/admin/images/dummy-logo.jpg')}}" id="imagePreview" class="organisation-logo" alt="Your image will appear here.">
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Here is my code from where I am updating the data and the image. Please check this

```
   public function update(Request $request, $jobId)
   {

       try 
       {          

        if(isset($request->company_image) && $request->company_image->getClientOriginalName()){
            $ext = $request->company_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;     
            $request->company_image->storeAs('public/company-logo',$file);
        }
        else
        {
          if(!$company_image){
            $file='';
          }
          else{
            $file = $company_image;
          }
        }

           $data = [
               'job_title' => $request->input('job_title'),
               'job_description' => $request->input('job_description'),
               'publish_date' => Carbon::parse($request->input('publish_date'))->format('Y-m-d'),
               'closing_date' => Carbon::parse($request->input('closing_date'))->format('Y-m-d'),
               'company_image' => $file,
               'organisation_type' => $request->input('organisation_type'),
               'organisation' => $request->input('organisation'),
               'country' => $request->input('country'),
               'state' => $request->input('state'),
               'city' => $request->input('city'),
               'posted_by' => $userId
           ];

           $rs = null;
           if($request->input('temp_job') == 1){
               $rs = Job::updateOrCreate(['temp_job_id'=> $jobId], $data);
           }
           else{
               $rs = Job::where(['id'=> $jobId])->update($data);
           }

           if($rs){
               $message = array('flag'=>'alert-success', 'message'=>'Job Updated Successfully');
               return redirect()->route('auth.job.index')->with(['message'=>$message]);
           }

           $message = array('flag'=>'alert-danger', 'message'=>'Unable to update new job, Please try again');
           return redirect()->route('auth.job.index')->with(['message'=>$message]); 
       } 
       catch (Exception $e) 
       {
           $message = array('flag'=>'alert-danger', 'message'=>$e->getMessage());
           return back()->with(['message'=>$message]);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I am using something like same while uploading then no issue, but why it is showing this error while updating. I don't understand

Comment: Where is `$company_image` set?

Comment: Try to use `@if (!empty($company_image))` on your blade file.

Comment: I have already , added view code, can you please check the resource code section

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Make sure , you are passing `company_image` variable in view.

Answer (score 0):

```php
if(!$company_image){
    $file='';
}else{
    $file = $company_image;
}
```

problem is here, you need to make sure `$company_image` is [declared](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp), before you can use it in `if` statement inside controller.

Example:

```php
//declare company_image
$company_image = ''; //or $company_image = null;

//here logic to change $company_image if needed

//check if not empty/false
if(!$company_image){
    $file='';
}else{
    $file = $company_image;
}
```

Also you can check if variable exist with `isset()`:

```php
if(isset($company_image) && !$company_image){
    $file='';
}else{
    $file = $company_image;
}
```

Also make sure you pass this varaible in `view`. `view('myView', compact('company_image'))`

**Updated Answer:**

```php
//Declare file as empty
$filePath = '';

//check if file uploaded and is valid
if($request->hasFile('company_image') && $request->file('company_image')->isValid()){

     //get file extension
     $ext = $request->company_image->extension();

     //Generate File name
     $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;

     //Save file, storeAs() will return stored file path
     $filePath = $request->company_image->storeAs('public/company-logo',$file);
}
```

Use `$filePath` to update the path in `DB`

```php
$data = [
...
'company_image' => $filePath,
...
];
```

In `view` you can simply use `{{ asset($company_image) }}` check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files)

**Complete update function**

```php
public function update(Request $request, $jobId) {
    try{          

        //Declare file as empty
        $filePath = '';

        //check if file uploaded and is valid
        if($request->hasFile('company_image') && $request->file('company_image')->isValid()){

            //get file extension
            $ext = $request->company_image->extension();

            //Generate File name
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;

            //Save file, storeAs() will return stored file path
            $filePath = $request->company_image->storeAs('public/company-logo', $file);
        }

        $data = [
           'job_title' => $request->input('job_title'),
           'job_description' => $request->input('job_description'),
           'publish_date' => Carbon::parse($request->input('publish_date'))->format('Y-m-d'),
           'closing_date' => Carbon::parse($request->input('closing_date'))->format('Y-m-d'),
           'company_image' => $filePath,
           'organisation_type' => $request->input('organisation_type'),
           'organisation' => $request->input('organisation'),
           'country' => $request->input('country'),
           'state' => $request->input('state'),
           'city' => $request->input('city'),
           'posted_by' => $userId
        ];

        $rs = null;

        if($request->input('temp_job') == 1){

            $rs = Job::updateOrCreate([
                'temp_job_id'=> $jobId
            ], $data);

        } else{

            $rs = Job::where([
                'id' => $jobId
            ])->update($data);

        }

        if($rs){
            return redirect()->route('auth.job.index')->with([
                'message' => [
                    'flag' => 'alert-success',
                    'message' => 'Job Updated Successfully'
                ]
            ]);
        }

       return redirect()->route('auth.job.index')->with([
            'message'=> [
                'flag' => 'alert-danger',
                'message' => 'Unable to update new job, Please try again'
            ]
       ]); 

    }catch (Exception $e){

        return back()->with([
            'message'=> [
                'flag' => 'alert-danger',
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In first example, when I update it removes the stored image.  and in second example, same issue

Comment: @Bhawesh Updated

Comment: When I use your updated code, and remove  else
        {
          if(!$company_image){
            $file='';
          }
          else{
            $file = $company_image;
          }
        }

Comment: @Bhawesh added a complete `update` function, you need to make sure you know what you are doing, read About PHP and Laravel.

Comment: Problem is here $filePath = '';  When i submit without selecting file, the stored file is removed

Comment: Then don't update if is empty, you need to load the `model`/ record before.